# Get a bean created in another module, which current module does not have dependency of

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to get a bean created in module B from module A, if module A does not have dependency of module B?

I have a bean created in moduleB like this

```
@Configuration
public class ModuleBconfig() {
  @Bean
  public SomeBean getBean() {
   return new SomeBean();
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get this bean from module A via global Spring context, where the moduleA does not have dependency of moduleB.

Comment: Did you try? Because as you've explained your use case it should work...

Comment: I did try, which seems not working, just want a confirmation for that. I have been searching the web for the answer of that.

Comment: Are these actually Java 9+ modules or are you using the word in a different context?

Comment: No, actually Java8

Comment: Then what do you mean by module? And please provide the code where you did try!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get, just the same as you get Spring beans:

```
 @Configuration
public class ModuleAConf {
    @Bean
    public String getB(SomeBean f, ObjectMapper p) {
        f.doSometghing(); // your bean
        p.getDateFormat(); // object mapper from Spring context

        return "test";
    }
}
```